# flash of unstyled content for a second when we use modernizr to load our resourses dynamically

Tags: css, html, modernizr

I am using modernizr to detect media query support so that i could load fallback css and js. But the issue is there is a flash of unstyled html and then css is applied as the css is loaded by the modernizr dynamically.it looks ugly for a while.any solutions ?

```
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
            yep: ['test.js','/a/s/responsive-css/abcd.css'],
            nope: ['/a/s/xyz.css']
        });
```

check this link.
http://susheel3656.0fees.net/index_with_modenizr.html

Comment: You could include a base stylesheet on the page that at least makes everything look okay, since that will be loaded when the page loads. And then have your additional stylesheets load afterward and the modified styles should cascade appropriately.

Comment: Or hide your page with JS and use a callback function to show it once rendering is complete. jQuery fadeIn() works well for that.

Comment: http://susheel3656.0fees.net/index_with_modenizr.html
check this link. it show up just for a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using either [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) or [CSS3-MediaQueries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) to add media query support for (mainly) IE7 and IE8?

Load the responsive css for everyone then change your modernizr call to something like:

```
Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
        yep: ['test.js'],
        nope: ['/js/respond.js']
 });
```

I've had some good success with this approach. Worst case scenario is that visitors on just IE7 or IE8 might have a flash on unstyled content.

If you need even more tweaks for older brosers you can include conditional comments in the page head, adding an ie tag or loading js scripts, and finally in your CSS include extra CSS specific to the browser eg:

**HTML**

In the head: [EDIT]

```
<script>
Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
        yep: ['test.js'],
        nope: ['/js/respond.js']
 }); 
</script>    

<!-- load the responsive CSS for everyone -->    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/a/s/responsive-css/abcd.css" type="text/css"/>  

<!--[if IE 7]>  
<html class="ie7">  
<script src="/js/ie7-script.js">    
</script>  
<![endif]-->
```

**CSS**
Then in the CSS add

```
.ie7 .additional-selector{
/* Optional css specific to IE7 to compensate for old browser. Ideally this wouldn't be needed */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah the flash of unstyled content is what i don't want to see. it is even visible in chrome or any other browser :( styles are getting applied late due to modernizr i think so ??

Comment: Yes you are correct, I just updated my suggestion to reflect what was in my head ;)

Comment: I am including dynamically using modernizr by checking the query whether the browser support media queries or not if yes then load a js and my responsive css else load the normal css. Now if i do as you said this will override my responsive css :(

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand your question. The general idea of what I'm suggesting is include responsive css for everyone, then use modernizr to check for media query support. If it's not there load respond.js . Ideally you wouldn't need to load any other css. I've used variations on this method with sites which are responsive for IE7 and IE8 and there's no problem with FLOUT.

Comment: i am not considering **internet explorer** at all. Even if responsive behavior doesn't work its ok for internet explorer because i will load a separate css for those doesn't support media query and responsive css for those which support media query. So now what is happening is modernizr loads asynchronously as you know. so now body  is loading  sooner than modernizr itself. And css styles are being applied from modernizr so there is a flash of unstyled content. If  i include the common css it outside modernizr it overrides my responsive styles.

Comment: May be respond.js may not support for some mobiles then it would be a mess.

Comment: Media query support is good for mobile browsers (http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) so in practice the challenge is to find support for IE8 and maybe IE7. Respond.js and css3-mediaqueries.js aren't a guaranteed fix for every site but if they work for you it's a nice, clean solution. Hope you find something that works well for you!

Comment: i checked in one of my phones which doesn't have media queries and normal html was shown without css so i wanted modernizr to load resources based on media query support instead of trying and fixing it using other third party js which would not be completely feasible as you mentioned. so i just want to load css and js based on media query support. tell me some solution based on that if u can... thanks for your replies with patience.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer ? Since modernizr loads it assets async there will be a flash of unstyled content.

Comment: @pike, with the code posted in the question, users on both new and old browsers would potentially see a flash of unstyled content, viewers on old browsers aren't getting a full experience of the responsive site, and site developer needs to maintain 2 sets of CSS file. I suggested an option where you send the responsive CSS to all (ie no flash if you have a new browser), then use Modernizr and Respond.js or CSS3-MediaQueries.js to help visitors on older browsers.  Better experience if you have a new browser, visitors with older browsers  see the responsive site and one css file to maintain.

Comment: Ah - yes , I see .. I overlooked the hardcoded <link rel="stylesheet" there. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Modernizr init code at the beginning of your head tag. It did not look like much loaded before modernizr.js but it might be worth a try.

If this does not work, a work around would be hiding your page content and use jQuery to show your content when the css is loaded.

Comment: yes modernizer code is in the head tag itself but still no luck. hiding the body on document ready is also not working because till the body is not loaded we cant hide it.

Comment: @susheel If you were going to hide it on load, you'd do that using css rather than js. The js is used to show it again. Note that I'm not suggesting you do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem earlier today and came up with what seems to be a decent solution for the content flash.

The CSS: `html.js { display:none; }`

The jQuery: `$('html.js').show();`

Modernizr adds the js class to a page if it has JavaScript enabled.  What this does is hide the whole page by default using CSS and then show it once the JavaScript kicks in.

Users that have JavaScript disabled won't be affected as Modernizr can't add the js class to the HTML tag.  They also shouldn't see the flash anyway as that's due to Modernizr itself, which is never loaded.  Hope that helps!